# "Three way" vs. "Threesome"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, differences

My apology if I'm disrespecting the forum with such question, but after all we are here to learn.
Are three way and threesome different from each other?
Have I written "Three way" correctly?

Comment: Please include full context where you would use the words. Playing golf or what I am thinking you are thinking?

Comment: I assume you're referring to sexual encounters here... can you confirm?

Comment: Please include your own research in your question.

Answer (score 2):

A **threesome** is a group of three people.

A **three-way** is a sex-act performed by a group of three people, or as a modifier, it can refer to a situation involving three entities, as in

**There was a three-way tie for first place. What an amazing photo-finish!**

Comment: I'd be happy to know the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you, but I think the OP wants to know the difference between each word when both are used as a reference to a sexual encounter.

Comment: He doesn't say so. And is there a difference when the context is limited to sexual encounters?

Comment: I'm not the DV either, but it might be because of your first statement; 'threesome' is also widely used (in the UK at least) to mean  three-person group sex. I have also started seeing it used in this way on American TV where hitherto only 'three-way' was used.

Comment: A **threesome** is a sex act performed by three people who don't know grammar.

Comment: Yes, threesome is a group of three people. +1) for the answer and comment.

Comment: Another driveby downvoter, a plague on this site.

Comment: @deadrat Yes, indeed.

Comment: *More whining & griping about anonymous downvotes, another plague on this site. Sigh*. Anyhow, I can't agree with this; it implies _threesome_ isn't a sex act. But don't argue with me, take it up with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threesome), take it up with Google images (link omitted, NSFW), take it up with [Vogue](http://www.vogue.com/12371340/how-to-have-a-threesome-breathless-karley-sciortino/) and [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/love-sex/is-a-threesome-ever-a-good-idea-in-a-relationship-10241969.html).  Maybe I don't know grammar, but I know usage.

Comment: (BTW, Tim, just to be clear, by "whining and griping," I wasn't referring to your comment, but to the chatter further down in the comments. Your request for more information was constructive.)

Comment: @J.R. Attestations can sometimes be evidence of widespread malapropism, though I suppose that for some radical descriptivists, there's no such thing as malapropism. The threesome are the doers, not the deed.  One cannot *engage in* a threesome. One can have sex as part of a threesome. The only way to *do* a threesome is when **do** means "have intercourse with", in which case it would be a foursome, or if one threesome is doing another threesome, a sexsome.

Comment: @TimR - Thanks for the clarification. If you added those insightful clarifications to your answer instead of just leaving them here in a comment to me, I'd happily remove my downvote. Moreover, if you went even further, and added yet another side note acknowledging that [some](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/threesome) [dictionaries](https://www.wordnik.com/words/threesome) – [for better or for worse](https://www.google.com/#q=%22have+a+threesome%22) – have expanded their definitions to accommodate pop culture, then I'd go all the way, and upvote your answer as well.

Comment: @J.R. wordnik and Macmillan's are "open", inviting submissions from a (self-selecting) public and thus they suffer from the sort of skewing of data that can occur when a website runs an unscientific poll addressed only to those who frequent it.  A poll on lovepanky.com, say, about what the word **threesome** means would probably generate far different results than one addressed randomly to speakers at large.

Comment: Actually, Wordnik cites from multiple sources; most (though not all) are built as wiki dictionaries. Still, your larger point remains true: crowdsourced dictionaries are often the first to adapt and "validate" new words and usages. FWIW, OED lists this usage of _threesome_ (Cf. ménage à trois *n*.) under a header marked `Draft Additions June 2013`. That entry currently cites four usages: one goes back to 1939; another is from a 1969 movie review published in *The Times* (London). I still think this is all quite interesting from an ELU perspective, and deserves some mention in this lone answer.

Comment: @J.R. Macmillions in its definition of **threesome** refers to it as an "occasion".

Comment: @Tim - Well, that "occasion" is apparently more than just "a group of three people." Anyhow, thanks for your clarifications; I found them quite informative.