# American English: 3-way, or 3 way ... which is the correct word usage?

Tags: word-usage

3-way or 3 way. Which is correct usage?

Comment: Define "correct". I suspect most grammarians would say all bets are off as regards correct hyphenation if you're going to mix digits and letters in a single syntactic element like this. But for the actual *word* form, [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+three+way+split%2Ca+three-way+split&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20three%20way%20split%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20three%20-%20way%20split%3B%2Cc0) clearly shows that we nearly always hyphenate ***a three-way split***, for example. And that's hardly AmE-specific.

Comment: a 3-way or three-way valve. And AmE is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Question: 3-way or three-way?

It depends on context:

a 3-way control valve or a 3-way switch. In technical contexts, 3-way is very much the usage.

In other, non-technical contexts, one usually writes: a three-way approach or a three-way conversation, etc.

[3-way](https://www.grundfos.com/service-support/encyclopedia-search/3-way-valve.html)

Comment: See also TRomano's answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/291265/three-way-vs-threesome

Comment: A three-way sexual encounter is non-technical. [joke]